# Typescript index signature not providing proper intellisense in intelliJ (works in vscode)

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

So I was exploring index signature in typescript looking for better ways to improve my code flows and I noticed something that feels like a flaw, and im wondering if maybe my configuration is somehow the issue.

So essentially

```
export function setAge(test: { [test: string]: string }) {
  return test;
}

setAge(
```

when I type setAge, I should expect to see the test variable as an index signature with an internal key named 'test'.  However for some reason 100% of the time in intelliJ it shows as

`{ [p: string]: string }`

This seems incredibly counter intuitive to the major advantage of index signature over using something like Record.

Is there a configuration around this?  I had presented a presentation for my team on the concept, and it would be nice to know that its applicable to more than half my team.

Comment: but the key name doesn't actually matter here, does it?

Comment: in theory no, but intellisense is a very helpful tool when developing to communicate intentions.  And this works 100% as described in vscode.  I'm just looking to see if someone else has a solution for this before I open a bug report with intelliJ